# Trying to run a simple shell script to install VirtualBox Guest Additions

Tags: bash

Elementary is sorely lacking in ease of use beyond opening applications. Something as simple as running a shell script ought to work like it does in any other distro, but elementary fails at it. Trying to cd to the directory containing the script gives me a "no such file or directory" message. Now I know there is a damn directory there because I am looking at it in the file browser, so don't lie to me, Freya. I like the clean desktop environment, but when I am locked out of all but the most basic functionality, I am ready to storm away in frustration.

Comment: OK. Now it suddenly worked somehow.

Comment: If you expect any kind of help/advice, you should attach your script here.

Answer (score 2):

Just for interests sake - could you type history and put the last commands down on here to see where you went wrong, or why the system did that?
thanks